# Проверка на столкновения двух спрайтов в Pyglet(Python)

Tags: python, pygame

Созданы 2 спрайта (самолет и астероид, которые движутся навстречу).
При столкновении исчезает самолетик (так и задумано) и окно Pyglet сворачивается.

Как сделать так, чтобы самолет исчезал при столкновении, а программа продолжала работать?

```
from pyglet.window import key
from pyglet import image
import random
import pyglet

listplayer = []
window = pyglet.window.Window(800,450)

#asteroid = pyglet.image.load("a30003.png")
ast1 =pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img =pyglet.image.load("a30003.png") ,x = 400, y = 350)
listast = [ast1]
airdevice = pyglet.image.load("самолет2.png")
sm1 = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(img = pyglet.image.load("самолет2.png"))

class Player(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(img = airdevice , *args, **kwargs)
        self.x = 400
        self.y = 100
        self.speed = 20

    def check(self):
        if self.delete():
            self.speed = 0

    def update(self):
        self.check()
        self.y += self.speed
       
sm1 = Player()
listplayer.append(sm1)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    for i in listplayer:
        i.draw()
    ast1.draw()

def update(self):
    ast1.y -= 10
    sm1.update()
    if sm1.y >= ast1.y:
        sm1.delete()
        listplayer.remove(sm1)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 20 / 60.)
pyglet.app.run()
```

'''
ошибки:

```
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/number1/collisions.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/number1/collisions.py", line 56, in <module>
    pyglet.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\__init__.py", line 107, in run
    event_loop.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 167, in run
    timeout = self.idle()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 237, in idle
    redraw_all = self.clock.call_scheduled_functions(dt)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\clock.py", line 292, in call_scheduled_functions
    item.func(now - item.last_ts, *item.args, **item.kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/number1/collisions.py", line 51, in update
    sm1.update()
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/number1/collisions.py", line 32, in update
    self.y += self.speed
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\sprite.py", line 485, in y
    self._update_position()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\sprite.py", line 428, in _update_position
    x1 = self._x - img.anchor_x
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'anchor_x'
```

'''

Comment: из ошибок следующее: 

  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/number1/collisions.py", line 31, in update
    self.y += self.speed
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\sprite.py", line 485, in y
    self._update_position()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\sprite.py", line 428, in _update_position
    x1 = self._x - img.anchor_x
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'anchor_x'

Comment: и еще: Traceback (most recent call last):
 
 
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\app\base.py", line 237, in idle
    redraw_all = self.clock.call_scheduled_functions(dt)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\number1\venv\lib\site-packages\pyglet\clock.py", line 292, in call_scheduled_functions
    item.func(now - item.last_ts, *item.args, **item.kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/number1/collisions.py", line 46, in update

Comment: сложно читать. нажмите под вашим кодом кнопку 'править' , вставьте  там весь текст ошибок и добавьте ``` перед и после этого текста.

Comment: Если ошибки вылезают когда происходит столкновение, значит в 99% случаев нужно фиксить ошибки

Comment: Проблема была решена  обращением к sm1 не напрямую в методе update, как к обьекту класса, а путем пересмотра  списка(listplayer), который содержал sm1